# QGIS 3.12.3 - Startup Python Error: couldnt load SIP module

Tags: python, qgis

When I open the software, I get an error message as shown below. After closing the popup, the software can start up but no python plugin or functionality can be used.

> Couldn't load SIP module. Python support will be disabled.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\__init__.py", line 70, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in 
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Python version: `3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]`

QGIS version: `3.12.3-București 'București', 8234261527`

Python path:

```
['C:\\Users\\(user)\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\PyQt5',
'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', 
'C:/Users/(user)/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 
'C:/Users/(user)/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 
'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\DLLs', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin', 
'C:\\Users\\(user)\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: It would help if you could add some pertinent code instead of just the stacktrace.

Comment: @brojoe, It shows up as an error when I start up the software. It just seems to be a problem with the import files when QGIS starts up python support.

Comment: Here are some resources I found: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312173/importerror-no-module-named-qgis-core-on-windows-10  from the StackExchange GIS page.  Also, 

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31367   A known bug: Anaconda build not supported in QGIS 3.8.  Of course it should have been fixed by version 3.12, but you never know.  Start with these.  Maybe someone else has better knowledge.

Comment: After Reinstalling, I get a slightly different error.

`ImportError: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of Python.`

Comment: I'm not sure but It sounds like the version of QGIS that you're using is compiled for Python 2.7.  You could try manually replacing the dll with the version of Python that you're using. Also, are you running the latest and greatest QGIS version 3.14?  Also check your environment settings to verify you have the correct version of Python in your path.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling with the OSGEO4W installer for multiple versions of QGIS and the problem persists. The same goes for QGIS version 3.14 and 3.10.